# Why is a CSS file saved with the wrong MIME type: text/troff?

Tags: css, mime-types, mime

I need to upload a .css file on a service.
Normally my css file have the MIME type

```
text/css
```

Now i have a css file which gets denied from the service because its not a css file.
The CSS file now has the MIME type

```
text/troff
```

Saved it multiple times as a new .css file and checked for any unclosed comments and bugs, but even PHP Storm is not showing me any errors.

What is the reason a css file gets saved as a text/troff MIME type?

Comment: Poorly i cant share the css file...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the service is running on a server which denies the creation of a `text/css` file and saves it using the other MIME type as a fallback. I think you cannot do anything but change some configuration on that server or the contact the service you are using for this.

If you create the file in your computer and then upload it to the server, then it could be the same issue, the server or the service doesn't accept that MIME type.